# conditional statements under for loop to export csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am converting CSV file to a data frame using python. The data frame looks like follows:
[image]

My task is to search for all rows in this dataframe and find values such that (startlat should lie between 18 to 20, and startlon should lie between 72.5 to 75). When I find these values I have to export those specific rows into seperate csv. I have done code in python which extracts lat and lon data from dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
# read in data to use for plotted point

############################# Open your csv file ################################
dataset = pd.read_csv('MyData.csv', delimiter = ',')
a=len(dataset.index)                                           # "a" is number of rows CSV has 
print(a)
################################################################################
for i in range(0,a):

    start_latitude=str(dataset.iloc[i,2])
    start_longitude=str(dataset.iloc[i,3])
```

How do I make a condition such that it exports the entire row whose start_latitude lie between 18 and 20 and start_longitude between 72.5 to 75

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('MyData.csv', delimiter = ',')

# Set filter conditions beforehand.
condition_1 = (18 >= dataset['StartLat']) & (20 <= dataset['StartLat'])
condition_2 = (72.5 >= dataset['StartLng']) & (75 <= dataset['StartLng'])

# Filter based on conditions.
filtered_dataset = dataset[condition_1 & condition_2]

# Export filtered dataset.
filtered_dataset.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: @Ajinkya if this works for you, please consider accepting this answer as correct.

Comment: I dont think dataset[2] is a correct way to take value of a dataframe it is giving error due to this on condition1 &2